# Desktop PC won't turn on, have to hold down Case's power key while flipping PSU's power key to turn it on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power

I assembled a computer about a month ago. Asus HERO, GTX 970, 1TB, i7 6700K, 1250W XFX Gold.

About a week after, it wouldn't start. The lights on the Main were lit, but the system just wouldn't power up. So I flipped the PSU's switch a few times, while holding the power key of my case, and it turned on. Continued to do this for about two weeks, till yesterday. No matter how many times I flipped the PSU's switch, the PC wouldn't power up. So I opened up the PSU, and found a bad capacitor. Replaced it, and tried again. Still no luck. Wouldn't power up normally by just pressing the power key once, had to hold the power while flipping the PSU's switch to power the damn thing on.

Is this a PSU problem, or a MB problem? After the PC powers up, it runs like it's supposed to, even under heavy load. So I think the MB is probably fine. On the other hand, there was no other visible damage inside the PSU other than that one capacitor which I replaced.

What do you think?

Comment: Do you have any other PSUs you can swap in to see?  I would try that.

Comment: remove all added components ram, fans, hdd etc.. get it down to its bare bones and try power it on then, if it works, success, add one component at a time, I've had similar issues with dodgy cpus where the  pc would turn on sometimes but not others.

Comment: Tried that already, without any success. There was no sign of a short, or a bad cap, or any other visible damage on MB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Such a diagnosis is really hard to make, since we only have what you wrote. Errors in power supply or motherboard can be really strange. Personally i think a problem with the power supple is likely. The best way to find out would be replacing the components. In that case i would try to change the power supply and test how this works out. 
PS: Do you really need a 1250W power supply though? 600-700 should be enough i guess. I don't think thats the problem though.

Comment: Going to short the Pins and try to turn on the power with all cables disconnected. I think the PSU is the culprit as well, after all a PSU that busts a cap within a week of coming out of the box is not to be trusted. Never ever going to buy XFX again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure anyone out there having the same problem can find out what is wrong with his/her PC.
Before doing anything, unplug the PSU from the socket and flip the back switch to off. Remove all power cables from PC components, GPU, CPU, MB, etc. 
Now look for your Motherboard Power cable, short the green wire with one of the black wires. If you have a modular PSU, make sure to attach MB power cable to the back of PSU as well. Now plug in your PSU, and flip the back switch to 1. If nothing happens and the PSU does nothing and it's fan is not spinning, then congratulations, you have a bad PSU. Even if your PSU passes the test, there is no guarantee that it's actually going to handle the load when it's attached to other components.
My problem was exactly the same. A faulty PSU. All i can say is i am never going to buy XFX again. I replaced it with a coolermaster for now, but i am going to fix it and post some pics of defective components that were the cause, maybe it would be of some help to someone in the future facing the same problem.